# ng new Error: EPERM: operation not permitted syscall unlink

Tags: angular

i try ng new but npm give this error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted syscall unlink

```
 I already do this npm cache clean --force but it not resolve problem
```

version

node v10.13.0

npm  v6.4.1

windows 8.1 64bits

this is a part of log file
after this warning

```
Line 10351: 16353 warn tarball tarball data for @angular/cli@~7.1.2 (sha512-SruaZsmyq3+ymMPeMJSzhytvgtvzyzb1q58pUYX+vZjff2aMYOo0TVxJALwTOPIABICTqUTZmujbLG9uxVgxFA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
    Line 10353: 16355 warn tarball tarball data for @angular/compiler@~7.1.0 (sha512-AvYXtjEJ27Rhv4c27DXNEa58Lit63jdydzbz7VuyFhNU+FwDUK2DC4gZe0nWZsf7HUniJezVRFkECDCZQeSKCQ==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
    Line 10374: 16376 warn tarball tarball data for uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@^1.2.4 (sha512-ovHIch0AMlxjD/97j9AYovZxG5wnHOPkL7T1GKochBADp/Zwc44pEWNqpKl1Loupp1WhFg7SlYmHZRUfdAacgw==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
    Line 10406: 16408 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\cli.d.ts'
    Line 10408: 16410 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\cli.js'
    Line 10409: 16411 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\cli.js.map'
    Line 10413: 16415 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\index.d.ts'
    Line 10414: 16416 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\index.js'
    Line 10415: 16417 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\index.js.map'
    Line 10416: 16418 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\logger.d.ts'
    Line 10418: 16420 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\logger.js'
    Line 10419: 16421 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-dev-server-88fa4a37\lib\utils\addEntries.js'
    Line 10420: 16422 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\logger.js.map'
    Line 10421: 16423 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-dev-server-88fa4a37\lib\utils\createCertificate.js'
    Line 10422: 16424 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\options.d.ts'
    Line 10423: 16425 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-dev-server-88fa4a37\lib\utils\createDomain.js'
    Line 10424: 16426 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\options.js'
    Line 10425: 16427 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-dev-server-88fa4a37\lib\utils\createLogger.js'
    Line 10427: 16429 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\options.js.map'
    Line 10428: 16430 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\programs.d.ts'
    Line 10429: 16431 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\programs.js'
    Line 10430: 16432 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\lib\cli\programs.js.map'
    Line 10435: 16437 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-989aa32c\src\libsass\.editorconfig'
    Line 10437: 16439 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-989aa32c\src\libsass\.gitattributes'
    Line 10446: 16448 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\animations-8f77e185\esm2015\browser\src\dsl\style_normalization'
    Line 10447: 16449 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\animations-8f77e185\esm2015'
    Line 10449: 16451 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\animations-8f77e185\esm2015\browser\src\private_export.js'
    Line 10457: 16459 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webdriver-manager-0beb71a1\built\config.json'
    Line 10460: 16462 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\reactive_directives\form_control_directive.d.ts'
    Line 10462: 16464 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\reactive_directives\form_control_name.d.ts'
    Line 10464: 16466 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\reactive_directives\form_group_directive.d.ts'
    Line 10466: 16468 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\reactive_directives\form_group_name.d.ts'
    Line 10467: 16469 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\reactive_errors.d.ts'
    Line 10469: 16471 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\select_control_value_accessor.d.ts'
    Line 10471: 16473 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\select_multiple_control_value_accessor.d.ts'
    Line 10472: 16474 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-3707e302\lib\webworker\WebWorkerChunkTemplatePlugin.js'
    Line 10473: 16475 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-3707e302\lib\webworker\WebWorkerHotUpdateChunkTemplatePlugin.js'
    Line 10474: 16476 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\shared.d.ts'
    Line 10475: 16477 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-3707e302\lib\webworker\WebWorkerMainTemplate.runtime.js'
    Line 10476: 16478 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\template_driven_errors.d.ts'
    Line 10477: 16479 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-3707e302\lib\webworker\WebWorkerMainTemplatePlugin.js'
    Line 10479: 16481 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\directives\validators.d.ts'
    Line 10480: 16482 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\webpack-3707e302\lib\webworker\WebWorkerTemplatePlugin.js'
    Line 10482: 16484 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\form_builder.d.ts'
    Line 10484: 16486 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\form_providers.d.ts'
    Line 10485: 16487 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\forms.d.ts'
    Line 10486: 16488 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\@angular\forms-888c7b2f\src\model.d.ts'
    Line 11836: 16507 warn ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
    Line 11837: 16508 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: node-sass@4.10.0 (node_modules\node-sass):
    Line 11838: 16509 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\node-sass-989aa32c'
    Line 11841: 16511 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: gauge@2.7.4 (node_modules\gauge):
    Line 11842: 16512 warn enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: Cannot cd into 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\gauge-4
```

this is error

```
error path F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-5a3654b4\README.md
16521 error code EPERM
16522 error errno -4048
16523 error syscall unlink
16524 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-5a3654b4\README.md'
16524 error  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-5a3654b4\README.md']
16524 error   cause:
16524 error    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'F:\IUT_Semestre_5_6\stag\ProjetDeStage\gescours\node_modules\.staging\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-5a3654b4\README.md'
16524 error      errno: -4048,
16524 error      code: 'EPERM',
16524 error      syscall: 'unlink',
16524 error      path:
16524 error       'F:\\IUT_Semestre_5_6\\stag\\ProjetDeStage\\gescours\\node_modules\\.staging\\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-5a3654b4\\README.md' },
16524 error   stack:
16524 error    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'F:\\IUT_Semestre_5_6\\stag\\ProjetDeStage\\gescours\\node_modules\\.staging\\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-5a3654b4\\README.md\'',
16524 error   errno: -4048,
16524 error   code: 'EPERM',
16524 error   syscall: 'unlink',
16524 error   path:
16524 error    'F:\\IUT_Semestre_5_6\\stag\\ProjetDeStage\\gescours\\node_modules\\.staging\\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-5a3654b4\\README.md',
16524 error   parent: 'gescours' }
16525 error The operation was rejected by your operating system.
16525 error It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
16525 error or that you lack permissions to access it.
16525 error
16525 error If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
16525 error permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
16525 error the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
16526 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]`enter code here`
```

Comment: Do you have a virus scanner like McAfee running? Also, are you running command prompt as administrator?

Comment: have you remove node modules